# wordpress Add another custom field to custom posts

Tags: wordpress

I bought a theme and it comes with custom post types.

how can I add another custom field to the ones that are already there?

Comment: with this advanced custom fields, I can add to ones already there?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by the plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).
The option I prefer is registering a metabox in the functions.php with the [Metabox](https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/) plugin.